# Create if condition with modx UrlParam

Tags: modx-revolution

I got the value of the urlParam "image". No i want to show an image only if the Param is 1.

```
[[getUrlParam? &name=`image` &int=`1`]]
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MODX output filters](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/building-sites/tag-syntax/output-filters) to achieve this.

Using the output filters (`:eq` and `:then`) you can show the image as you wish.
The output of the `getUrlParam` snippet is automatically submitted to the output filter `:eq` which then checks the desired value.

Please make sure that you use an uncached snippet call in this case (`[[!getUrlParam...]]`) because you are dealing with data that changes every time the page is re-rendered/called. If you fail to do this the value of the GET variable will be cached after the first page call which will lead to inconsitencies in your desired result.

```
[[!getUrlParam:eq=`1`:then=`<img src="/foobar.png" alt="Some img">`? &name=`image` &int=`1`]]
```